# Adjust middle table cell to width of content

Tags: html, css, tablecell

The goal is for the middle table cell to adjust in width depending on the content inside of it.

I know this is possible on a table cell at the end using: ***width:1px; white-space:nowrap;***

However, I am not able to achieve this on a middle table cell.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Note: I know how easy this is in flexbox, not looking for flexbox solution.**

*Image for reference below.*

[image]

Comment: well, `width:1px; white-space:nowrap` works for a middle cell too! see this: https://jsfiddle.net/f1rtnxpj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use table-cell and use 1px width for center cell. left and right cell must be width auto:

```css
.table{ display: table; width: 100%;}
.left,.right,.center{display: table-cell; width: auto;}
.left{ background-color: gray;}
.right{ background-color: silver; text-align: right;}
.center{ background-color: black; color: white; width: 1px;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
   <div class="left">Content Left</div><div class="center">Content Center</div><div class="right">Content Right</div>
 </div>
```

If you need padding, just use inner div inside left, right and center div.

Comment: I was making a simple mistake of setting the table-layout to fixed, which was causing the cells to overlap.